# VisualStudio creates very unnecessary Merge-Conflicts when Rebasing?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

I have a weird problem working in VisualStudio 2019, with C# and Git:

We have a rather sizeable repository (thousands of classes and solutions in a single Repo, dozens of developers) and we've recently switched from TFVC to git.

We currently have our Master Branch that everyone is doing bugfixing on and Feature Branches that people are developing features on. Pretty standard so far.

Now the people who are developing the features are trying to re-integrate their changes into Master. Since Master has changed a lot and we don't want regression, developers are supposed to rebase their  changes on Master. Pretty standard again.

But from judging by everything I understand about git so far, the results are just not what I would expect. A rebase seems to create a merge conflict almost always. Every time something was changed in master I need to manually confirm that I still want those changes, by Resolving the conflict.

Why do I need to resolve conflicts if I haven't changed anything in that file? It's like it's asking me to manually confirm every change in every commit that has been made in the meantime.

I am guessing our settings are kind of fucked up, sadly I am not even sure where to look for that? It's not just "special" files either (csproj, sln, xml, resx, etc), they're completely normal .cs files with "normal" changes.

Rebasing in the console doesn't change this either and if I try to merge it instantly works and manages to resolve all conflicts?

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: It should resolve automatically, but maybe you have conflicting settings on different client. For example, if one person has line endings set to CRLF and onther to just LF that could cause issues like what you're describing. Inspect the conflicts and see why they are there - perhaps it's just a configuration everyone needs to change (or set in the repo)

Comment: Just like @fredrik says, probably you have settings messing up with files EOL. Are these conflicts full-file? Or just a section of the files? If it's full-file then it's EOLs being messed up.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys but no, it's not EOL errors. It's not whitespace, VS literally tells me that both files have been changed and compares the old version in my branch that I am trying to rebase, to the new version in the branch that I'm trying to rebase onto, asking for confirmation every time despite the old version, as it is in my feature branch existing on master at a previous point. Might this have something to do with git cutting corners because our Repository is too massive?

Comment: Visual Studio git conflicts are very bug-prone and faulty, even Rerere is not supported  in visual studio (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/improved-git-experience-in-visual-studio-2019/#comment-23243). TFS conflicts were so accurate but git hmm... rebase compares every previous commits from both side like a cross join but even a simple merge in VS produces "0 conflict" conflict cases (empty conflicts) or one line shows multiple lines change. In merge pane if we click on one line the scroll jumps to another line (another page actually). VS is awful in git , VSCode probably better.